# Display username of user who logs in (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

This seems like a very simple question but I'm new to Angular2 and I'm a bit confused by the relationship between components. I have a login page and when the user enters their username, I want the username to display on the dashboard, something like "Welcome, James".

I have a `login.html` page, a `loginHTMLcomponent` that has a `templateurl` to the `login.html` page and its parent which login.ts.
I have `dashboard.ts` which is a parent of `dashboard.component.ts` which (has the HTML for the dashboard page)

Basically how do I get the username from the input field in login.html to appear in dashboard.component.html...I've probably explained this awfully. Thanks.

I'll try explain it a bit clearer
In my login.html I have something like:

```
input type = "text" [(ngModel="name")]
```

And in my dashboard.component.ts, inside in my selector I would have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboardHTML',
    template:
    `
    <body>
      ........
      ..........
      <span ="user">Welcome, {{user}}</span>
      ...
      `
```

Update:
Just wondering is the correct way in approaching using a service.
In my `login.component.html` I have:

```
 <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Username" ngControl="username" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

In my `login.HTMLComponent`(which has a templateURL to `login.component.html`)  I have `export class LoginHTMLComponent{
        public name: {};
        /////`

And in my `name.service.ts` I have this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {LoginHTMLComponent} from "./LoginComponents/login.HTMLcomponent";
@Injectable()
export class NameService {
    getName(){
        return name;
             }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm calling name correctly here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to pass the username from the `login component` to the `dashboard component`, you should obtain it rather via a common `service`. The username is probably part of the response from the backend that logs your user in. That response, i.e. the logged-in user, is stored in a service, that can be injected into each of your components.

Services are often a good idea to exchange data between components that are not within a parent/child hierarchy.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Regarding your service

The service should not have a reference to the `LoginHTMLComponent` or any other component. Inject the `NameService` in the constructor of your `LoginComponent` (and `DashboardComponent`) like this

```
private constructor(private nameService:NameService) {...}
```

and, of course, import the `NameService`.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to vote up if this helped you.

Comment: I voted alright but I don't have enough posts for it  to display, if you have a chance, could you look at the edit I made to my post? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see. Added some lines to my post

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In your case a service might be good option. Store the login data in the service and access it from whichever component needs the data.
Decorate the service with `@Injectable()` and then inject it into your components.

Comment: I voted alright but I don't have enough posts for it  to display, if you have a chance, could you look at the edit I made to my post? Thanks