# Angular2 Display username on dashboard with details

Tags: java, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-services

am learning angular2/4 and trying to create a login page with username and password. I have two components LoginComponent and DashboardComponent. When the user enters the username and password the dashboard should show a welcome username message ( example "Welcome ABC"). I was able to create the login page , but not sure on how to handle the second part of the question, that is the dashboard should show me the user who logged in.  I followed the below stackoverflow " [Display username of user who logs in (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660482/display-username-of-user-who-logs-in-angular-2)" but couldn't achieve much from it. Below is my code. Any plunker example is much appreciated.   I also looked into http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial but it is storing the login details in a local storage and getting it from there. Is there any other way where we can get the user name on login. Thanks in advance. Code Below.

**auth.service.ts**

```
       import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
       import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
       import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
       import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
       import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
       import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
       import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
       import { User } from "app/demo/domain/user";

       @Injectable()
       export class AuthService {
           loginObject :User
           isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

           redirectUrl: string;
           constructor(private http: Http) { }

           login(username : string, password : string) {
               this.loginObject ={username: username, password: password};
               return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/ui/api/login/'+username, this.loginObject)
               .map((response: Response) => {
                   let user = response.json();
                   if (user) {

                      logged in between page refreshes
                      this.isLoggedIn = true;
                      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                   }
                });
           }

           logout(): void {
               this.isLoggedIn = false;
           }
     }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
     import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
     import { Router }      from '@angular/router';
     import { AuthService } from "app/demo/service/auth.service";

     @Component({
     selector: 'login',
     templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
     })
     export class LoginComponent {
     message: string;
     user: any = {};
     constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

     login() {
     this.authService.login(this.user.username, 
     this.user.password).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(this.user.username);
    // this.setMessage();
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
    // Get the redirect URL from our auth service
    // If no redirect has been set, use the default
    this.authService.redirectUrl = '/dashboard';
    let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? 
    this.authService.redirectUrl : '';
     // Redirect the user
    this.router.navigate([redirect]);
    }
  },
    error => {
    this.message ="Error: Username or password is incorrect";
      });
  }
  logout() {
  this.authService.logout();
  this.message = 'Logged ' + (this.authService.isLoggedIn ? 'in' : 'out');
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
 }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title>PrimeNG - ATLANTIS</title>

<!-- Layout CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/theme/theme-blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/layout/css/layout-
blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/pages/primeng.min.css">

<!-- Ripple -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body class="login-body">

  <div class="login-panel ui-fluid">
      <div class="ui-g">
          <div class="ui-g-12 logo-container">
              <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
              <h2>WELCOME TO SKYCREEK</h2>
          </div>
   <p style="color: #ff0000;">{{message}}</p>
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" 
    novalidate>
        <div class="ui-g-12" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && 
     !username.valid }">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off"  class="ui-inputtext ui-
     corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget" name="username" 
    [(ngModel)]="user.username" #username="ngModel" placeholder="Username" 
  required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block" 
   style="color: #ff0000;">Username is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && 
   !password.valid }">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="ui-inputtext 
   ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget" name="password" 
 [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" 
 required />
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block" 
   style="color: #ff0000;">Password is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 button-container">
            <button class="ui-button green-btn ui-widget ui-state-default 
    ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left">Login</button>

        </div>
    </form>

  </div>
      </div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Basically you need to learn communication between component. There are various ways to accomplish this checkout this link. [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) .

Comment: @HirenParekh. Thanks for the reply. I gave @Input('user') userName: String; in my dashboard and gave {{user}} in dashboard.html. But it doesn't display anything

Comment: Why are you having html tags etc in your component? These belong only in index file